# How to fetch database values and show them in drop down menu?

Tags: html, drop-down-menu, phpmyadmin

I want to create a table in phpmyadmin and store some values in this table and show these stored values in one drop down menu in html form. How do i create that table and store these values and then show them in drop down menu?

Answer (score 1):

**You Can Do that Using SQL Statements To Retrieve/Fetch data from Database.**

you can Use Select Query For Fetch Data From Database as Used in Example Below:

```html
<?php
//db connection
mysql_connect("localhost","user","password");
mysql_select_db("database");

//query
$sql=mysql_query("SELECT id,name FROM table");
if(mysql_num_rows($sql)){
$select= '<select name="select">';
while($rs=mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
      $select.='<option value="'.$rs['id'].'">'.$rs['name'].'</option>';
  }
}
$select.='</select>';
echo $select;
?>
```

Comment: can i show drop down list in html textfield by this?

Comment: <label>abc</label><select name="abc" id="abc"><option value="pick">Select an option</option><?php
$conn = mysql_connect("localhost", "root","","db")or die("cannot connect");
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");
    $sql=mysql_query($conn,"SELECT names FROM student");
    $row=mysql_num_rows($sql);
    
    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
     echo "<option value='". $row['names'] ."'>" .$row['names'] ."</option>" ;
    }
    
    ?>
   </select>

Comment: try to use **mysqli** instead of **mysql**

Answer (score 0):

You can use SQL Statment for the database part:

1. To create a table https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_create_table.asp
2. To insert the values https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert.asp

You can find a simple php script that will allow you to o fetch and print the 
data https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_select.asp